# Password prompt on status update or profile update event?

Tags: passwords, facebook-authentication

I'm looking for docs in order to understand if I can subscribe to a status update or profile update event and then ask the user for their password in an in-facebook app?

This is to stop other people from picking up your phone, logged in browser and playing a joke by updating these :-)

Is there a trigger to subscribe too?

Comment: I'm thinking if I can hook into an update before it is accepted and then request a new OAuth token by redirecting to the facebook auth page presenting say, "Please approve this update" and then redirecting back to the page and my app makes the update. That would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently Facebook does not offer a way to moderate feed posts this.  As you probably found out they do allow you to subscribe your application to a user's events.  However, the action is not really stopped for moderation.

Comment: Facebook privacy fails again! 5 years on and still nothing.